# Angular JS ng-pattern for whole numbers

Tags: angularjs, regex

Am trying to get right regex for whole numbers from 0 to 99 without any special characters.

My html is like this

```
input id="term" class="form-control" type="number" min="1" max="99" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" name="loan_term" ng-model="xxx">
```

When I checked this regex in https://regexr.com/, its not showing match for value like '22.'

But in my application its not showing error for '22.' but when I use 22.5 its showing error.

Its letting me to add number with dot at the end

What would be the proper regex or am I doing anything wrong on declaring?

Comment: You should use `/^\d+\.\d{0,2}$/;` for decimal number

Comment: What abou a non decimal numner then?

Comment: `/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/g` this one for both